# Array filled and displayed in function but no displayed in tableview swift

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift3, alamofire

I am having trouble with an array that it is filled correctly in a separated function, the issue is when i try to fill in the elements of my cell in my tableview, i can only find the last element however when i want to display the number of elements in that array while filling the cell it displays the correct number of elements, can anybody help please.
this is my function for retrieving and filling in the array:

```
  func downloadUserDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete){

    let Ful_Url = "http://192.168.1.4:8888/phps/select.php"

    Alamofire.request(Ful_Url).responseJSON(completionHandler:  { (response) in

        if let userDect = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]{

            for ex in 0...userDect.count-1
            {
                if let firstnames = userDect[ex]["firstname"] as? String{
                   self.users?.firstname = firstnames}

                if let emails = userDect[ex]["email"] as? String{
                    self.users?.email = emails}

                if let lastnames = userDect[ex]["lastname"] as? String{
                    self.users?.lastname = lastnames}

                 print("---------------------------------")


                self.items.append(self.users!)

               // self.items.insert(self.users!, at: self.i)

                print(self.items[ex].email)
                print(self.items.count)
                }
        }
        completed()
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    })

}
```

this is how i am trying to fill the cell's labels:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("####################")
    print("nombre items")
    print(self.items.count)
    return items.count


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"myCell" , for:indexPath)

    let email:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UILabel
    let firstname:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UILabel
    let lastname:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(13) as! UILabel

        print("=========================email=========================")
        print(items[indexPath.row].email)

        email.text = items[indexPath.row].email
        firstname.text = items[indexPath.row].firstname
        lastname.text = items[indexPath.row].lastname


    return cell

}
```

Comment: Copy/paste code, do not post screenshot of code.

Comment: `self.items.insert(self.users!, at: self.i)` why?

Comment: im filling the array each time i find a user and i increment i at the end of each loop

Comment: same thing as append, i will change it the way it is a clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i have just found the solution for any one who faces the same problem, it is actually very simple, the declaration of Class User should be inside the loop, not as a class variable, so now i create a new user at each element found and i add the old element to the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think trouble in insert method:

```
self.item.insert(self.users!, at:self,i);
```

You can try :

```
self.item.insert(self.users!, at:ex);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is that you are using one single instance of user and then appending it to the array, Each item in the array points to the same item (classes are passed by reference).

You do not need to do this, you dont need to maintain a count or index during iteration either.

This code should work fine..

```
if let usersDict = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] {
    self.users = usersDict.map({ dict in 
        let user = User()
        if let firstnames = dict["firstname"] as? String{
            user.firstname = firstnames }

        if let emails = dict["email"] as? String{
            user.email = emails }

        if let lastnames = dict["lastname"] as? String{
           user.lastname = lastnames }

        return user
    })

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Or even better, allow your User object to be intialised with a dictionary and then do

```
if let usersDict = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] {
    self.users = usersDict.map({ User($0) })

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Just use local variables during your loop, no need for class properties here. To use the bottom one, you will need to be able to initialise the User object with a dictionary. Similar to this method:

```
struct User
{
    var firstName:String
    var lastName:String
    var email:String

    init(dict:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {
        email = dict["email"] as? String
        firstName = dict["firstName"] as! String
        lastName = dict["lastName"] as! String
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I just wrote this in a playground which works fine

```
class User {
    var firstName: String!
    var lastName: String!
    var email: String!

    init(dict: [String:AnyObject]) {
        self.firstName = dict["firstName"] as! String
        self.lastName = dict["lastName"] as! String
        self.email = dict["email"] as! String
    }
}

let usersDict: [[String:String]] = [
    ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "email": "john@example.com"],
    ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smithy", "email": "john@example.com"],
    ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Stevens", "email": "john@example.com"],
    ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smithen", "email": "john@example.com"]
]

let users = usersDict.map({ User(dict: $0 as! [String : AnyObject]) })

for user in users {
    print(user.firstName, user.lastName)
}
```

Output:

```
John Smith
John Smithy
John Stevens
John Smithen
```

Comment: thank you for responding, i have one more question do i add that struct in my User class ? or in the function that im using to get the data

Comment: what is self.user in your project? in the downloadUserDetails function?

Comment: it is an initialisation of my User class :     var users:User? = User (email:"aa",firstname:"bb",lastname:"cc")

Comment: see the init function in my struct above... you can use a similar function inside your User Class

Comment: that is exactly what i did but it gives me an error : 'map' produces'[T]' , not the expected contextual result type User?

Comment: let me double check it, give me few minutes

Comment: I updated with test code from a playground I written to test

Comment: i can retreive users and i fill the array just find, that is not the issue, the issue is in the tableview i can only see the last element, your solution worked for me in my function but the same thing it didnt in the tableview

Comment: I think the issue is using self.user in your code to build the array. First thing you should do is ensure that not all items in the array are actually the same. before you call completed() do `for item in self.items { print(item.firstname) }` to make sure they are different. then we can look at the problem

Comment: actually you are right sir, it shows me one item two times

Comment: This is a bit confusing to explain but this is because you are adding an item, then modifying the item and adding it again. when you modify self.user you change self.user and the item you added to the array. the code I used above should get around this. See in my first example, I create a NEW user every time with `let user = User()`

Comment: when i use print inside the loop i get all elements but outside the loop it shows only the last element

Comment: yes, it prints its current value. see this article which helps explain it. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

Comment: i found the solution thank you very much for your support

Comment: glad to of helped